# resize chat bar on mobile

Tags: css, mobile

Like in the following picture I would like to make the chat bar  on shop pages a bit smaller on mobile devices for this page: **ergotopia.de** 
I tried it with this code, which makes it smaller but the opened window as well (like you see in pic).

```
@media (max-width:849px){
      .single-product.zopim{
               margin-left: -10px;
               margin-bottom: 38px!important;
              width: 37px!important;
     }
  }
```

How to adjust this code, so the bar is small, but the opened window as big as normal?

I also tried this, but without success:

```
@media (max-width:849px){
      .single-product.zopim{
               margin-left: -10px;
               margin-bottom: 38px!important;
       .single-product.zopim .jx_ui_Widget{
              width: 37px!important;
     }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post the full code of the window or pass the site url please?

Comment: please pass the Site url

Comment: Thanks for fast response. I did, but maybe not obviously its www.ergotopia.de

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Below CSS to achieve your goal, make min-width of button_bar to auto and hide the button_text

```
@media (max-width:849px){
   .meshim_widget_components_chatButton_Button .button_bar{min-width:auto;}
   .meshim_widget_components_chatButton_ButtonBar .button_text{display:none;}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: it works beautifully by onsite editing, but when I put it into backend custom css it doesnt. Thats quite strange. May it be a result of, its a script loaded external (zendesk)?

Comment: Yes this is the issue most of the time but let me recheck on this, could you create a user and give some right to put css and check . so I can debug it with custom css

Comment: Try using important with css because class name remains same on each load , so this can help

Comment: I did, but not working. Thank you very very much for your help. I wrote ZenDesk if they have a solution for this, as I cannot give access to others.

Comment: They will help you, I saw mobile small button available in upgraded version, If you have upgraded version then I can tell you settings where to do that